# Which word is closest in meaning to "prospered" in this context, "enriched" or "succeeded"?

Tags: word-choice

Which word is closest in meaning to *prospered* in the following text, *enriched* or *succeeded*?

> With the arrival of the traffic-free shopping street, many shops, especially those selling things like clothes, food and smaller luxury items, **prospered**. Unfortunately, shops selling furniture and larger electrical appliances saw their sales drop […].

Comment: shops prospered, especially etc. Move the verb.

Comment: I don't know of any use of "prosper" that means "enrich". Where did you find that definition?

Answer (score 1):

With the arrival of the traffic-free shopping street, shops, especially those selling things like clothes, food and smaller luxury items, prospered [or [**succeeded**](https://www.lexico.com/definition/succeed)]. --Lexico definition 1 and 1.1.

Other good choices are:

- [profited](https://www.lexico.com/definition/profit), [thrived](https://www.lexico.com/definition/thrive), [expanded](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/expand) (more formal)
- [did very well](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/do%20well) (less formal)
- stayed open for business a long time (less formal)

*Enriched* is not the right synonym here. It does not mean became rich, but caused something else to get rich (causative). So you could say the mall enriched some stores at the expense of others.

**Variation per Lambie:**
With the arrival of the traffic-free shopping street, shops prospered, especially those selling things like clothes, food and smaller luxury items.

Comment: How about some documentation?

Comment: shops prospered and then the rest